# How Magento controller redirects work?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have made Magento controller that redirects to url, but for some reason url is wrong.

My controller:

```
public function indexPostAction()
{
    // Do stuff here
    $this->_redirect('module/controllername');      
}
```

This controller redirects to url module/controllername/indexPost, but I have redirected it to module/controllername which is my index page of my module. Why it is not redirecting to correct address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That redirect will redirect you to www.yourstore.com/module/controllername which is controlled by the `indexAction` function of the `controllername` controller. What does the `indexAction` function do? If you just want it to display the content of the layout, so you would do that with

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: Thanx for help, I actually had error in my code so that never reached that redirect code, but it didn't throw any errors to magento log, so I didn't catch that until I debugged code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A
[proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve
its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make
it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer
to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.